# C# Activator.CreateInstance() drops "Cannot create an abstract class" exception

Tags: c#, dll, activator

I am trying to dynamicly load .DLL file and run one of its methods (actually there is only one method..) but the Activator.CreateInstance method drops an "Cannot create an abstract class" exception
This is my code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(DLLByteArray);
//Type typeToExecute = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
//last line was replaced with the next one to ensure that the name is correct.
Type typeToExecute = assembly.GetTypes()[0];
Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToExecute);
```

the class deceleration if needed: "`public static unsafe class Class1`".

Does anything in the .DLL class code can cause this kind of exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(DLLByteArray);
Type typeToExecute = assembly.GetTypes()[0];
typeToExecute.GetMethod("TheMethod").Invoke(null, theArguments);
```

That will invoke a static method with an `object[]` (theArguments) containing all method arguments

The other solution is simply to remove the `static` keyword from the class and the method (which will make your current code work)

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to create an instance of a static class. You can't do that - it doesn't have any constructors (a static class is both abstract and sealed).

The message is pretty clear about this: "Cannot create an abstract class".

Why were you *trying* to create an instance of this class? You say you want to invoke a method, but why did you think that would require you to create an instance? Even if you could have created the new instance, you shouldn't have been doing so in order to call a *static* method. I'm assuming the method is static, as otherwise it couldn't be placed in a static class...

You should think carefully about *exactly* what you want to do when you use reflection - because the compiler isn't going to be able to spot when you're doing something non-sensical. Without reflection, it would have been able to:

```
// Fails at compile-time
new ClassLibrary1.Class1().WhateverMethod();
```

You need to think like a compiler when you're using reflection - because the compiler can't do it for you.

Comment: Hint: Read the first line in the question.

Comment: I want to run a method from a file placed as an embedded resource.

Comment: @eranj: If it's a method within a static class, then it must be a *static* method, so you shouldn't be creating an *instance* of it.

Comment: THANKS :)
I was doing +1 but unfortunately i cant.